# How to remove every odd line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to edit a document of 20000 lines. I have to remove every odd line, say for example:

```
Apple
Monkey
Orange
Lion
fruit
animal
```

How can I remove every odd line's characters in the document?

Comment: what do you mean by odd line? Do you mean like to remove the odd (unwanted) word from the entire document?

Comment: Every odd numbered lines like 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15....so on.

Comment: Try replace with new line (regexp): [\n.+\n]

Comment: @ArtGertner i tried with the expression its not working.

Comment: Sorry, I never really use Notepad++, My previous example was tested on Sublime Text. I forgot that its a Windows software. If you are on windows then likely you will need `\n,+\r\n`

Comment: I d record a stupid macro: down arrow, shift-down arrow, del.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would a macro detect the end of the document and stop?

Comment: @ArtGertner the button >> Run until the end of file

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it with find and replace:

- Open the replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Select "Regular expression"
- Find what:
  `.+\r\n(.+(\r\n|$))`
- Replace with: 
  `$1`
- Press "Replace All"

Notes:

- Depending on your OS you need to use `\r` (old Mac), `\n` (Unix, OS X) or `\r\n` (Windows) to match end of line, or just use `\R` which should work everywhere (thanks for @Aurel Bílý)
- `\n|$` is needed to have correct result even at the end of the file
- By default, Notepad++ replaces from actual cursor position to the end of file. Make sure to place your cursor to the beginning of file.

  - (You could also check "wrap around", but in that case it will first delete the line your cursor is in, instead of really looking for an odd line.)

[image]

Comment: It almost works, but it is not editing the first set of odd numbered lines, say from 1 to 15.

Comment: Change the screenshot with more transperacy of that replace window.

Comment: Please note that `\r` as a line ending is very rare – it was indeed used in Mac OS, but the classic, pre-OS-X versions. In OS X an onwards, line endings are `\n`, like any sane Unix. Also `\R` is better for matching any line ending.

Comment: @AurelBílý That's true, however Notepad++ only runs on windows, so portability here isn't much of an issue.

Comment: "Invalid regular expression"

Comment: @DigitalDracula it works for me and apparently for several other people too. Maybe you can ask another question where you can post screenshots and explain how exactly you try to use it.

Answer (score 19):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+\R(.+)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+      : 1 or more any character but newline
\R      : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
(       : start group 1
  .+    : 1 or more any character but newline
)       : end group 1
```

- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
Monkey
Lion
animal
```

Comment: @NithinN: Be aware that accepted answer doesn't work with linux files (ie. linebreak `\n`)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open the file and put your text cursor at the start of the first line.
2. Menu → *Macro* → *Start Recording*
3. Press the <kbd>End</kbd> key on keyboard
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>, then <kbd>backspace</kbd>
5. <kbd>Down</kbd>
6. <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
7. <kbd>Down</kbd>
8. Menu → *Macro* → *Stop Recording*
9. Menu → *Macro* → *Run a Macro Multiple Times* → Tick *Run until the end of file*
10. Click <kbd>Run</kbd>

Basically perform the action once to remove an odd line, then get the program to repeat the action to the end of the file. This can be used to solve many problems!

Answer (score 1):

I just checked on my colleague's PC who actually uses Notepad++. Try this:

[image]

Comment: It seems to me this to remove even lines (2,4,6...), not odd ones.

Comment: That is correct. However removing even lines is easier, and the problem can be resolved by adding an empty line at the beginning of the file

Comment: @ArtGertner should be \r\n.+\r\n replaced with \r\n

Comment: @chingNotCHing, good one! I've updated my answer

Comment: @ArtGertner As you pointed out it works for even lines only. But for large set of data it is not editing for first set of data say from 1-15th line.